# Finding R^2 for specific groups in an nlme model in R

Tags: r

First, let's recognize that it is not my choice to look at R^2 with non-linear models.  But I have to do it.

I have six treatments and four reps in each treatment.  I fit a logistic model to each treatment.  I need to find the R^2 for each fit to treatment.  I can find R^2 for the model over fixed effects (over all treatments), but then I get confused with how lists work in nlme.  How can I ask for something specific to the random effect (each treatment)?

Maybe this plot will make things clearer.  The code I'll post will give me the R^2 for the blue line, but I want R^2 for the pink lines.

[Link to plot of predicted values](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k92jyd8a0zzs2q8/accumulative.pdf)

Here is the code I have run so far:

```
#Changes in root biomass over four years in 6 different cropping systems
yr<-read.table("totalfallmass2.txt", header=TRUE)
library(nlme)

yrG<-groupedData(mass ~ year | trt, data=yr)

fit.log <- nlsList(mass ~ SSlogis(year, Asym, xmid, scal), data = yrG)

fit.nlme <- nlme(fit.log, random = pdDiag(Asym ~ 1))

plot(augPred(fit.nlme, level = 0:1))

#For an overall R^2
cor(fitted(fit.nlme),getResponse(fit.nlme))^2
```

And here is the data you would need to run it:

[Text file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hakwg9rph5pmsd2/totalfallmass2.txt)

Comment: And here is the fortune for your data or your reviewer: `library(fortunes); fortune("nls")`

Comment: Ha! Thanks, @Dieter! Perhaps I should keep fighting.

Comment: I can feel with you. Had similar cases like this before.